# Is there a way to detect win service pack with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, user-agent

I know the OS name can be retrieved using the navigator object with javascript, but what about the service pack version?

Is there a way to do this with pure js? (without java or flash)

Answer (score 2):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

> Alternate tokens can appear in the
>   user-agent string for a number of
>   reasons; usually, they identify
>   optional features installed on your
>   system. For example, **an "SV1" token
>   appears in the user-agent string of a
>   user who has installed Windows XP
>   Service Pack 2 (SP2)**. It is also
>   important to note that certain
>   non-Microsoft parties modify the
>   user-agent string for their own
>   purposes.

It's SV1 because SP2 is also Security Version 1.  So you could do:

```
/sv1/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

...to detemine if SV1 is contained within the user agent string.  I wasn't able to find if there's any token associated with SP1.

Comment: I just found this: http://metasploit.com/svn/framework3/trunk/lib/rex/exploitation/javascriptosdetect.rb looks interesting.